# How can I get each cognito user with their groups using boto3

Tags: python, boto3

I need to list the users with each group that this has associated. I'm trying to do this:

```
client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')

response = client.list_users(
    UserPoolId=env_settings.pool_id
)

listUsers = response['Users']

for u in listUsers:
    print u
```

But I am within their properties does not return the group. I'm using the boto3 python client. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

ListUsers just returns user metadata but does not have group info. See the syntax of response from ListUsers API call [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html#API_ListUsers_ResponseSyntax). To get a user's group info, you would need to make [AdminListGroupsForUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminListGroupsForUser.html) API call. The corresponding boto3 call can be seen [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.admin_list_groups_for_user).